# is it possible to preprocess the input string before isearch-forward in Emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

For example, if I type "`foo spam`" after the prompt of `isearch-forward`, how can I advice some functions in `isearch.el` to convert the string to "`foo[.?:,!]?[ \n]spam`" before search? Basically I want to search for the two adjacent words in the text. I know I can use `isearch-forward-regexp` to do that, but it's painful and error-prone to type out the regexp directly and I have many strings of that kind to search. I tried to understand code in `isearch.el` but failed. hope some Emacs gurus could help me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a rough crack at it:

```
(defun isearch-transform-string ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((string (replace-regexp-in-string
                  "foo" "bar" isearch-string)))
    (setq isearch-string string
          isearch-message (mapconcat 'isearch-text-char-description string ""))
    (isearch-search-and-update)))

(define-key isearch-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-t") 'isearch-transform-string)
```

I think you have to bind it to a key in `isearch-mode-map`; I don't think M-x works quite right in `isearch-mode`.

If you require more power, there is a variable `isearch-search-fun-function`, which you can set to a function that returns a function.  The returned function is used to find the next match.

Comment: the first solution works but not ideal. I tried the second one but have an error, which I posted as another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16333324/defadvice-error-for-isearch-search-fun-default

Answer (score 4):

You may be interested in `isearch-toggle-word` (<kbd>M-s w</kbd>) during your incremental search.

http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Word-Search.html

This will search for individual words ignoring punctuation, spaces and line ends.

Comment: +1. I didn't know `M-s w` can search multiple words. However, I still think preprocess the input string for isearch is still valuable because it would provide a general solution to a wider kinds of problems. For example, even in this situation, what if one want to see two adjacent words in one sentence (without punctuations).